# Appodeal.REWARDED_VIDEO cordova not working! (onRewardedVideoFailedToLoad)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, appodeal

Sorry my bad english.

I'm starting on Appodeal sdk on Cordova project.
In the first day my code work fine, but now, stop to work.

On the event `deviceReady`

```
  var appoAppKey = "myAppKey";
  if (! Appodeal ) {
    alert( 'Appodeal plugin not ready' );
    return;
  }
  Appodeal.disableLocationPermissionCheck();
  Appodeal.initialize(appoAppKey, Appodeal.INTERSTITIAL | Appodeal.BANNER | Appodeal.REWARDED_VIDEO | Appodeal.NON_SKIPPABLE_VIDEO);
```

Call to Reward:

```
$scope.iniciarCompraVagaAnuncio = function(){
  Appodeal.show(Appodeal.REWARDED_VIDEO);
}
```

Listening callback:

```
Appodeal.enableRewardedVideoCallbacks(true);

document.addEventListener('onRewardedVideoLoaded', function(){console.log("onRewardedVideoLoaded")});
document.addEventListener('onRewardedVideoFailedToLoad', function(){console.log("onRewardedVideoFailedToLoad")});
document.addEventListener('onRewardedVideoShown', function(){console.log("onRewardedVideoShown")});
document.addEventListener('onRewardedVideoFinished', function(data){
    console.log(data);  //data.amount  - amount of reward, data.name - reward name
    $scope.compraVagaAnuncio(data);
});
document.addEventListener('onRewardedVideoClosed', function(){console.log("onRewardedVideoClosed")});
```

Almost every time:

> onRewardedVideoFailedToLoad

`Appodeal.show(Appodeal.INTERSTITIAL);` work fine on same buttom.